# How to find total percentage of students who are absent or tardy in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements

I have a grade_level and total_num_students columns but not sure how to create a column to get the percentage of students who are absent/tardy. (Each student id is unique and in both tables)

Here are the two tables:

[image: student_attendance_log]

[image: student_info]

And here is my current SQL query that I have so far:

```
SELECT     
grade_level,     
COUNT(student_attendance_log.attendance_status) AS 'total_num_students'     
FROM student_info    
INNER JOIN student_attendance_log    
ON student_info.student_id = student_attendance_log.student_id     
WHERE student_attendance_log.attendance_status = 'Tardy'     
OR student_attendance_log.attendance_status = 'Absent'      
GROUP BY grade_level        
ORDER BY grade_level;
```

which produces:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I recommend `avg()` for this calculation:

```
SELECT grade_level, COUNT(*) as total_num_students,
       AVG(CASE WHEN sal.attendance_status = 'Tardy' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END) as tardy_ratio,
       AVG(CASE WHEN sal.attendance_status = 'Absent' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END) as absent_ratio
FROM student_info si INNER JOIN
     student_attendance_log sal
     ON si.student_id = sal.student_id     
GROUP BY grade_level    
ORDER BY grade_level;
```

Note some changes:

- Table aliases makes the query easier to write and to read.
- Only use single quotes for string and date constants.  Don't use them for column names.
- The filtering has moved from the `WHERE` clause to the `AVG()`.